# webview SSL error handler

Tags: android, android-studio, android-security

I got a notification from google play store for my app

[image]

And here is my previous code .. after getting that error notification, I looked and read ssl error handler from google Android developers page .
Here is my previous code [image]

This one is my new one
[image]

But the same problem still exists!! Got the same notification after uploading new version

Comment: It has been a long time since you have asked this question. 
Did you find the solution to your issue?

Answer (score 7):

on received ssl error you need to cancel, not proceed:

```
handler.cancel();
```

instead of:

```
handler.proceed();
```

see google documentation here:

> To correct the issue, please update your apps code to invoke SslErrorHandler.proceed() whenever the certificate presented by the server meets your expectations, and invoke SslErrorHandler.cancel() otherwise.

https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7071387?hl=en

So basically you have done the exact opposite of what you needed to do to prevent this vulnerability ,-)